# insert file location into sql database SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible to import a file location into a database using ssis or any other function is SQL?? I have a directory full of audio files and want to insert the file path so that i can link it into a report. so the table would contain C:\Filepath\Filename.wav and a refrence number.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go. One, you could use a [`Foreach Loop Container`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx), retrieve the file path of each file and put it into a variable. Then use the variable in an [`Execute SQL Task`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx) to insert into SQL Table.

Another possibility is use PowerShell to list the contents of a directory, and write a CSV file. Then use that CSV file as a source in a Data Flow.